# Using LGA 775 CPU cooler on LGA 1155

Tags: cpu, motherboard, fan, cooling, lga775

So I have an lga 1155 mobo and cpu that I need a fan for, I do have a lga 775 (stock) fan which I have taken the plastic clips off of and it fits perfectly fine over the 1155 socket, my question though is how big are the risks involved if I mount the fan to the mobo using nuts and bolts, I have seen YouTube videos of people doing it but it seems to be alot of metal touching metal especially on the back where the nuts seem to touch the case, seems way to dodgy to try this although i am kind of stuck int he situation where I need the pc for the weekend and wont be able to get a 1155 fan till next week.

Comment: Provide specific product information on the heatsink if you want an answer.

Comment: Updated, its just a stock intel lga 775 fan and heatsink.

Comment: The stock cooling solution uses plastic screws.  Why are you concerned about non-existent metal components?

Comment: Because I have to remove the plastic screws to mount the 775 fan onto a 1155 socket. I am referring to the back of it, if say I mount the fan onto the mobo using the nuts and bolts then the back of the bolt is touching the case behind the mobo, did you read my entire question? -_-

Comment: I read your question.  I can take the hint, you don't want my help, so I bid you Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

When done carefully it is perfectly fine.

Depends on how exactly you mount it, there're brand coolers that mount via nuts and bolts and everything works fine.

Watch out for:

- shorting any motherboard non-insulated traces.
- it's quite easy to scratch the solder mask and make insulated into a non-insulated. some spacers may help here, for a short period of time even made from paper should do
- overtightening, the MB should not be bent and pressure should be even

If your nuts are touching the case - to be on the safe side you can just not install the MB into the case, but assemble everything in free air and run this way until you can get the needed parts

Answer (score 0):

If available to your region, your local hardware store will have a selection of nylon nuts and bolts that you can use safely.  Do not install with metal hardware to a LGA motherboard.  Accidents happen, and these will be permanent.  You can consider it a permanent solution, unless you want to upgrade your cooling system in the future.

If you cannot purchase nylon nuts and bolts and must use the computer, if you are not doing anything intensive such as gaming or video editing, you can lay the computer on its side and rest the heatsink/fan onto the cpu.  This is a temporary solution and should be treated as such, however idle temperatures should be the same.  Avoid bumping it if you wind up taking this route...